# How would I remove those small gaps on the bottom and right side of the navbar elements?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar

I'm trying to remove those small gaps between my `nav-link` elements and `navbar` on the bottom as well as on the right side, but can't seem to figure out. I tried setting `min-height: 0` and changing it to `display: flex` and tweaking the `justify-content` and `align-items` properties, but didn't achieve the desired outcome. How else could I make it work?

Here is the screenshot: 
[image: screenshot of the problem]

Here is my code:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#logo-container {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#navbar {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: green;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="logo-container"></div>
    
    <nav id="navbar">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#welcome-section">About</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this css

```
#navbar {
font-size: 1.4em;
width: 50%;
text-align: right;
background-color: orange;
/* padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; */
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> Using `flex` with `justify-content: flex-end;` we can achieve desire
>   result

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#logo-container {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#navbar {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: orange;
  /* padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px; */
  display: flex;
  align-content: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: green;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="logo-container"></div>
    
    <nav id="navbar">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#welcome-section">About</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```